# Update state of an array with objects inside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have an array with this format:

```
[{exerciseName: 'Pec Deck', reps: 0, sets: 0},{exerciseName: 'Push-up', reps: 0, sets: 0}]
```

[image]

This array is stored initially here

```
const [currentWorkout,setCurrentWorkout] = useState(props.workout.exercises);
```

I want to change the array state with this inputs

[image]

This is the code of the inputs

```
const editExercises = currentWorkout.map((exercise,i)=>{
    return (<li key={i}><div className="exercisesContainer"><div><span className='exerciseName'>{exercise.exerciseName}</span></div><div className="repsSetsContainer"><span className='exerciseSets'> Sets - <input id={`sets${i}`}  onChange={handleChange} className="inputNumber" name="sets" type="number"/></span><span className='exerciseReps'> Reps - <input id={`reps${i}`}  onChange={handleChange} className="inputNumber" name="reps" type="number"/></span></div></div></li>)
})

function handleChange(event){
    const {name, value, id} = event.target
   
    setCurrentWorkout(prevFormData => {
        prevFormData.map((exercise,i)=>{
            return {
                ...exercise,
                [name]:value
            }
      })
      return exercise;
    })
}
```

How can i update the array state when clicking on the check button?

Comment: Please may you include a text version of that data?

Comment: Can you also share what you've done in your `handleChange` function that your JSX is referring to?

Comment: The ReactJS docs provide a good overview on how to do this, I recommend having a look at [Updating objects inside arrays](https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#updating-objects-inside-arrays)

Comment: I suggest adding an `id` to the data and use a `map()` (it's immutable) when doing `onChange` to find the specific data to update

Comment: You need to `return` your mapped array `return prevFormData.map(...)` or remove the body `{` `}` from your arrow function. You don't need to `return exersise`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the index (or the `exercise` object itself) to `handleChange` to indicate which object to update.

You also need to return the new array to be the next state from the updater function passed to `setCurrentWorkout`.

```
onChange={e => handleChange(e, i)}
```

```js
function handleChange(event, i) {
    // ...
    setCurrentWorkout(prev => prev.map((exercise, j) => 
        j !== i ? exercise : {...exercise, [name]: value}));
}
```